# react component won't render. I've checked out other questions, can't see what I'm missing

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and building a simple app with a node/express backend and react front-end. I'm trying to render my App component. I've tried using `ReactDOM.render`, but I'm already importing render from 'react-dom' and making that change did nothing. The file path to the App component is correct. No errors. When I inspect the DOM, the div is empty.

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Hyzer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/application.css'>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id='app'></div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='build/bundle.js'></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here's the App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1> Hello World </h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Edited to add my webpack.config.js (with testing modules removed because they are irrelevant) based on requests for clarification below:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, 'front-end', 'index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: BUILD_DIR,
  },
 };
```

Comment: Is the javascript file being loaded correctly?

Comment: how are you generating the bundle?

Comment: I'm generating the bundle in the webpack.config.js with the output filename set to `bundle.js` and the path set to `./build/bundle.js`

Comment: In the webpack.config.js the entry is set using `main: path.join(_dirname, 'frontend', 'index.js')`

Comment: This should be the correct filepath './front-end/index.js'

Comment: In the webpack.config.js the context is also set to the `_dirname`

Comment: Not sure how to check if the javascript is being loaded correctly, any suggestions? Should I use an onload() ???

Comment: Did my answer help?  I plugged your code into codesandbox.io and it did not work but when i made the changes in my answer below it worked.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it didn't work for me. I'm using babel. Maybe I need to add plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sarah,

You need to change App.jsx to App.js then it should work.  Please change the file name and also when you import it into index.js

```
import App from './components/App.jsx';
```

make it:

`import App from './components/App.js';`

and change the file name from App.jsx to App.js

Comment: Thank you, I tried changing changing the filename, but the component still isn't rendering. The div remains empty.

Comment: @SarahLindmar Check out this link, it works!  https://codesandbox.io/s/nk4p83wnj0

Comment: Thanks, your set up is a little different than mine. I'll try to go through it carefully to see if I can get mine to render. I'll post an update and accept your answer if I can get it to work.

Comment: Thank you, @iceveda06, I changed the file names and I also had to change the directory I was bundling to. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I foolishly had webpack bundling to a location `build`. My project is being compiled to a directory `dist` where the copy of my `index.html` obviously also resides. Once I changed the location of the bundle and the `.jsx` filetypes following the answer given by @iceveda06, the app rendered as expected. Thanks!